# How can I automatically restart Apache and Varnish if can't fetch a file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I need to restart Apache and Varnish and email some logs when the script can't fetch robots.txt but I am getting an error

```
./healthcheck: 43 [[: not found
```

My server is Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Check if can fetch robots.txt if not then restart Apache and Varnish
# Send last few lines of logs with date via email

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
THEDIR=/tmp/web-server-health
EMAIL=dude@email.net
mkdir -p $THEDIR

if ( wget --timeout=30 -q -P $THEDIR http://website.com/robots.txt )
then
    # we are up
    touch ~/.apache-was-up
else
    # down! but if it was down already, don't keep spamming
    if [[ -f ~/.apache-was-up ]]
    then
        # write a nice e-mail
        echo -n "Web server down at " > $THEDIR/mail
        date >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo "Apache Log:" >> $THEDIR/mail
        tail -n 30 /var/log/apache2/error.log >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo "AUTH Log:" >> $THEDIR/mail
        tail -n 30 /var/log/auth.log >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        # kick apache
        echo "Now kicking apache..." >> $THEDIR/mail
        /etc/init.d/varnish stop >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        killall -9 varnishd >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        /etc/init.d/varnish start >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        /etc/init.d/apache2 stop >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        killall -9 apache2 >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        /etc/init.d/apache2 start >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        # prepare the mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo "Good luck troubleshooting!" >> $THEDIR/mail
        # send the mail
        sendemail -o message-content-type=html -f alerts@website.net -t $EMAIL -u ALARM -m < $THEDIR/mail
        rm ~/.apache-was-up
    fi
fi

rm -rf $THEDIR
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for (I prefer /tmp since it's removed after a reboot, so a fresh start).

```
#!/bin/sh
# Check if can fetch robots.txt if not then restart Apache and Varnish
# Send last few lines of logs with date via email

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
THEDIR=/tmp/web-server-health
EMAIL=dude@email.net
mkdir -p $THEDIR

if ( wget --timeout=30 -q -P $THEDIR http://website.com/robots.txt )
then
    # we are up
    touch /tmp/.apache-was-up
else
    # down! but if it was down already, don't keep spamming
    if [  -f /tmp/.apache-was-up ];
    then
        # write a nice e-mail
        echo -n "Web server down at " > $THEDIR/mail
        date >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo "Apache Log:" >> $THEDIR/mail
        tail -n 30 /var/log/apache2/error.log >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo "AUTH Log:" >> $THEDIR/mail
        tail -n 30 /var/log/auth.log >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        # kick apache
        echo "Now kicking apache..." >> $THEDIR/mail
        /etc/init.d/varnish stop >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        killall -9 varnishd >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        /etc/init.d/varnish start >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        /etc/init.d/apache2 stop >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        killall -9 apache2 >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        /etc/init.d/apache2 start >> $THEDIR/mail 2>&1
        # prepare the mail
        echo >> $THEDIR/mail
        echo "Good luck troubleshooting!" >> $THEDIR/mail
        # send the mail
        sendemail -o message-content-type=html -f alerts@website.net -t $EMAIL -u ALARM -m < $THEDIR/mail
        rm /tmp/.apache-was-up
    fi
fi

rm -rf $THEDIR
```

Comment: Hmmm very strange, it worked 3 times and now it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Tyler Doesn't work in what way?

Comment: I forgot to change one of the `~/.apache-was-up`'s. How about now?

Answer (score 2):

```
if [[ -f ~/.apache-was-up ]]
```

In Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to [dash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dash.1.html) instead of [bash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html). dash is a minimal shell designed for scripts, whereas bash is more featured and designed for interactive use. The `[[ <expression> ]]` syntax is only implemented in bash, not in dash, and therefore you receive that error. The `[ <expression> ]` syntax is enough for what you need though, so change that line to this:

```
if [ -f ~/.apache-was-up ]
```

Comment: After copying Jay's script I changed the top line to /bin/bash and it worked fine the first three times I ran it then it just stopped working.

Answer (score 2):

While the script may work, there are some issues with it, like unsafe use of temporary files.

You really should have a look at [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), its open source and it is easy to write a rule that will restart your web services based on service responses. It can also detect if a running process dies (e.g. its PID goes away) and you have the possibility to temporary deactivate a check (e.g. when you are doing a service maintenance).

Comment: I added some instructions below on how to use Monit specifically in this use case.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a detailed answer on how to use Monit to monitor and restart Varnish if it is down.

First, visit http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-install-and-setup-monit-linux-process-and-services-monitoring-program/ to get some basic information on Monit and get it installed. This is a helpful tutorial since it gives the default paths for both RHEL/CentOS and Debian/Ubuntu.

Second, visit https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/monitoring-varnish and follow the instructions about setting up Varnish monitoring.

Here are a few notes from my setup:

- I would recommend using the URL /varnish-ping for the VCL ping URL. It's a logical path that is easy to remember. You can test this out once set up by running `curl 127.0.0.1:80/varnish-ping` from the command line & making sure it returns a 200 response.
- Make sure you have the right Varnish pid. As stated in the second article, you can find that in the init script. Mine was actually /var/run/varnish.pid. You can do an ls to make sure that file exists while Varnish is running.
- You will probably want to allow access to the Monit web interface to help in monitoring. If you have a firewall, you will first need to add port 2812 to the allowed ports. Then, change which IP's are allowed to access as per http://digitizor.com/how-to-enable-monit-web-interface-from-all-ips-and-change-port/. You can specify your own remote IP instead of 0.0.0.0/8 for greater security. Note that the password is passed through HTTP Auth, so you should not use a password that you want to keep particularly secure.
- Make sure that the Monit log is active. Check the "set log" log to make sure it has something like `set log /var/log/monit.log` on it.
- If installing Varnish doesn't put it on the list of daemons to start on a system reboot, you will have to add it via chkconfig (or the Ubuntu/Debian equivalent). I ran `chkconfig --list` to confirm it was present.

Hope that helps present a more reliable alternative. Note that you can also add in email monitoring for services via Monit as well.  Here's some more details specifically about email alerts: https://fak3r.com/2010/04/10/howto-use-monit-to-monitor-sites-and-alert-users/